# PDF with type 3 fonts looks better after pdf2ps: how can I convert it back?

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have a PDF from someone else that uses type 3 fonts and so is almost unreadable on screen (example: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~goguen/pps/tcs97.pdf ). If I run pdf2ps on it and open the PS in evince, the fonts look fine however.

Example before/after:

[image]

Since there's evidently a way to make the document render properly, is there a way I can convert it back to PDF and preserve the good-looking fonts? ps2pdf produces output that looks just like the original input.

I have a feeling this should be such a standard task (given how often I see type-3 font PDFs) that there should be an easy way to do this. Some ghostscript options perhaps?

My system is ubuntu 12.04/precise and I can install any package or download free software that may help; I've already got a full TeX, ghostscript and pdftk installation if that helps.

Comment: Was your original link supposed to be an example of font that looks bad? When I view it in Firefox Adobe Reader plug-in, it looks like your second image.

Comment: I can confirm that the firefox plugin somehow renders the original well too - but the linux stack of PDF tools (evince/poppler) makes it look like the first example.

Comment: Someone where I work suggested using mupdf (uses its own renderer). With this, the pages look fine. Question solved (for me).

Comment: Reported here: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107346